# Query join with SSIS parameter

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

It is possible to use parameter (SSIS variable) after left join in query in OLE DB Source? The query looks like:

```
...
FROM X
LEFT JOIN ?
...
```

where "?" is string variable, which I dynamically changing (based on loop iteration).

When I put this string, except "?" - it works. When I deleted it and parametrized I got:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provider
>   might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In
>   that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which
>   the entire SQL command is stored in a variable.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error
>   (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I use MS 2008R2.

Comment: Create a variable that contains the entire query as an expression. Assign the variable to your OLE DB Source (SQL command from variable).

Comment: You can't use parameters instead of tables  in SQL (not just SQL server), unless you are passing a TVP. Parameters are meant for *parameters*, eg `WHERE someField = ?` not core objects.

Comment: @JodyT The OP has already tried and asked a similar question involving dynamic SQL a few hours ago. The issue is that the OP is trying to find a way to pass a table name as "parameter" instead of writing a parameterized query

Comment: @JodyT My query is longer than 4000 char, so I can't do it.

Comment: @BNPTestovir I see. I have not used BIDS in ages. This limitation seems to be removed from SSIS 2012 and higher versions.

Comment: It's any workaround for 2008R2?